# Speed up the QFileDialog File Browser displaying folders/files in the default directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside2, qfiledialog

Operating System: Win10, QT:PySide2

I implemented a programm in python, that aquires images from a camera. This image-aquisition sequence is triggered by pushing a button "Start Sequence". To determine a saving directory for the images I am using QFileDialog. The button "Start Sequence" therefore first opens up a filebrowser where the user can choose the folder, where it wants the sequence to be stored. Then the image aquisition is started. The code for the filebrowser looks like the following:

```
def get_dir(self, name) # name is only a string
    start_dir = "D://data_someperson//"
    dialog = QFileDialog()
    options = dialog.Options()
    options |= dialog.DontUseNativeDialog # i dont know what this is doing, but without it nothing works
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
    filename = dialog.getExistingDirectory( None, name, start_dir, options = options)
    return filename
```

As mentioned the code above opens a filebrowser in the "start_dir" location. So the filebrowser would start up in "D://data_someperson//" from where the user can create a new folder or choose an existing one. This is then returned as "filename", where the image aquisition code stores the camera pictures. Now this works under the condition that the start_dir is equal to the working directory of my program. E.g. I run my main program via VScode in "D://data_otto" and start_dir is set to "D://data_otto". Here the file browser displays instantly (as it pops up) all existing files in "D://data_otto" and the user can easily create new folders without any problems.

My Problem now is the following: If "start_dir" is not equal to "D://data_otto" (eg, it start_dir is equal to "D://data_peter") the file browser pops up as usual in "start_dir" but basicly tries to "load" every existing file on my machine before it displays the files in "start_dir", where the user is supposed to choose a saving directory. This is also true when the user creates a new folder in "start_dir". If the user creates a new folder and confirms it in the gui, the function "getExistingDirectory" still waits for all files to be loaded, sort of in the background.

This delays my data aquisition by up to a minute. "D://" is a Hard Drive DT01ACA100 1TB and ~800Gb are occupied. I think my problem could be solved by using a faster drive, but there must be a way to restrict the Filebrowser's scope of files it loads to display, but i cant find such a workaround in the documentation... I observed, that the folders and files in start_dir are cached once they were loaded for a short amount of time. Extending this time would help aswell...

Comment: Do you have some network mount of sorts? What do you mean with "nothing works" next to `DontUseNativeDialog` flag? Have you tried to run your program *outside* vscode? (Unrelated, but still worth noticing: `getExistingDirectory` is a static function, you don't need to create an instance for it, as that function creates one on its own, you can directly use `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(...)`)

Comment: Hello. "nothing works" here mean that basically the program freezes in the function that is supposed to open the file browser and is not responsive anymore.

Comment: The network thing could be true since this pc was used by several people accessing servers over our internal network. There are two "Network locations" listed under this PC (Y: and Z:) that appear to be nonacessible (indicated by a big red cross).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it appears as I solved my problem by disconnecting two unaccessible "Network locations" that appeared under "This PC" as the drives "Y:" and "Z:". They where unaccessible (indicated as a Red cross in the Explorer), since the PC was disconnected from its local network and was moved to a different one. So just hit right click on them and choose "Disconnect" in the drop down menu to remove these "Network Locations". After that I had no more problems with the File Browser and everything needed is displayed instantly. No more delays/loading/buffering. THANKS goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante.